# Выведение значение из массива

Tags: php, массивы

Мне нужно вывести только значения из массива. Но в нем присутствуют значения и массивы. Как мне это сделать?

Массив:

```
Array
(

[query] => Array
    (
        [ids] => Array
            (
                [0] => 35080600
            )

        [dimensions] => Array
            (
                [0] => ym:s:date
            )

        [metrics] => Array
            (
                [0] => ym:s:goal33151467users
                [1] => ym:s:users
            )

        [sort] => Array
            (
                [0] => ym:s:date
            )

        [date1] => 2017-09-05
        [date2] => 2019-02-22
        [limit] => 50
        [offset] => 1
        [goal_id] => 33151467
        [group] => day
        [auto_group_size] => 1
        [quantile] => 50
        [offline_window] => 21
        [attribution] => Last
        [currency] => RUB
    )

[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [dimensions] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => 2017-09-05
                            )

                    )

                [metrics] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 220
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [dimensions] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => 2017-09-06
                            )

                    )

                [metrics] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 3
                        [1] => 218
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [dimensions] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => 2017-09-07
                            )

                    )

                [metrics] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 4
                        [1] => 206
                    )

            )
        )
```

Код:

```
foreach ($Data['data'] as $key) {
        foreach ($key as $r) {
            echo '<pre>';
            echo $r[0];
        }
    }
```

Результат:

```
Array - не должно быть
1
Array - не должно быть
3
Array - не должно быть
4
```

Comment: Есть `is_array`

Comment: Нужно, чтобы выводились числа, то есть - ['data'][0]['metrics'][0]. Но последний 0 он воспринимает, как массив. Должны быть только числа - 1, 3, 4

Comment: А, я вас понял.

Comment: Плохо смотрел в документацию php.

Comment: А чем плох `$key['metrics'][0]`?

Comment: Тоже подходит. Сейчас проверю

Comment: u_mulder - то что нужно. Так бы и не догадался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понятно в чем у вас затруднения. Все подмассивы в `'data'` имеют одну и ту же структуру, поэтому:

```
foreach ($Data['data'] as $item) {
    echo $item['metrics'][0] . '<br '>';
}
```